# How does `import = ` format work without `require()`?

Tags: typescript

I see something like

```
import foo = Bar.baz.lorem;
```

in some source code and it does not have a `require()` call. Is this an old form if import? I don't see any examples in the docs.

Comment: Have you checked out the compiled output? I'm 99% sure it converts it to `require`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is TypeScript syntax for importing from [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), not modules. There was a time when namespaces were called "internal modules", and modules were "external modules". So `import` from namespace can be used to introduce an alias to some entity defined in that namespace:

```
namespace Bar {
    export namespace baz {
        export const lorem = 42;
    }
}

import foo = Bar.baz.lorem;
```

This `import` is compiled into simple `var` statement

```
var foo = Bar.baz.lorem;
```

and, except for its confusing name, has nothing to do with ES6 or CommonJS modules.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to manually use `var` or `const` instead of `import`, but in that case it seems to lose type information.